# compare two same-size files, character by character, to generate a third of equivalent size

Tags: text-processing

I have two lists of strings, all of equal length.

Example:

```
String A1: ATTCAGAATG
String A2: TGCCAGATAC

String B1: 0010011010
String B2: 0111010100
```

I want to compare A1 to B1, A2 to B2, etc. character by character and modify the character in the A strings if there's a 1 in the same location in the B string.  I want to leave it alone if the character in the B string is a 0.

The result of comparing A1 to B1 should be `ATxCAxxAxG` and I want to store that in a third file.

There are two text files of equal size and length, each containing a sequence on a single line.  When the process is complete, there should be a third file of equivalent size and length, which is sort of a merger of the two.

This is a one time job, so I'm willing to do something hacky using only bash or something, although if some other script or simple c program is a more sensible way of handling the situation, I'm open to that too.

What are your suggestions for the simplest way to handle this?

Comment: How many strings? Solutions differ as order of magnitude increases.

Comment: Do the "prefix" strings like `String B1: ` belong to the files?

Comment: It's about 100 strings/lines in each file. The prefix strings are not in the files. They're just for clarification in the question.

Comment: @Tomatobot In your most recent comment, you say that each file contain 100 sequences, yet in the question you say "each containing a sequence on a single line."  which I interpret as a single sequence per file.  Could you clarify this please?

Comment: Each sequence is on its own line, so there are about 100 sequences per file. No line has multiple sequences.  In other words, there are no delimiters, unless you consider EOL as a delimiter. Another way to say it is each "line" is a single sequence or string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
paste file1 file2 |\
awk '{
    len=length($1)
    for(char=1; char<=len; char++)
        printf (substr($0, char+len+1, 1)+0)? "x" : substr($0, char, 1)
    print ""
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking a lot from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/398556/108618) to [another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/398481/108618).

```
paste <(od -An -vtu1 -w1 fileA) <(od -An -vtu1 -w1 fileB) \
| awk 'NF!=2{exit}; {printf "%c", $2==49?120:$1}'
```

49 is decimal value of ASCII `1`, 120 is decimal value of ASCII `x`.

Requirements like in the linked answer:

> You need a shell (like the GNU shell) with process substitution support, a `od` with support for the `-w` option (like GNU `od`), […]

The two files must be aligned perfectly, byte by byte. In general "byte by byte" is not equivalent to "character by character" you requested, but for files containing `A`, `C`, `G`, `T`, `0`, `1` and newline characters there is no difference.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond, but this code blew my feeble mind! αғsнιη's answer was easier for me to process. I do appreciate the help though! For what it's worth, I tried your code and it didn't work, for the reason described in your caveat. My bash didn't like the -w option with od.